# Associate a specific color to pie chart data in highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts, colors, pie-chart

The pie is as shown below
[image]

is there a way to associate ace falling load to color say orange , 3 -point technique to green
tried with

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: ['#F64A16', '#0ECDFD',]
});
```

this works fine on load if a user applies a filter some time ace falling load might not come then the color suffuses is there a way to tick the color to a value always in highchairs

please point to a sample

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve that is by specifying each point's colour inside the `series.data`

```
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    data: [{
      name: 'Red',
      y: 10,
      color: '#ff0000'
    }, {
      name: 'Green',
      y: 10,
      color: '#00ff00'
    }, {
      name: 'Blue',
      y: 10,
      color: '#0000ff'
    }]
  }]
```

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1sh5kp93/